# Did Stack Overflow’s IP address just change?

Tags: support

From sometime this afternoon, when I try to visit Stack Overflow from any device at home I get a 502 response:

> 502 Bad Gateway
>
> The server returned an invalid or incomplete response.

When I lookup the IP address of `stackoverflow.com` through my router’s DNS server, I get `198.252.206.25`. However, if I perform the lookup direct through Google’s `8.8.8.8` or even SO’s nameservers directly, I get `198.252.206.16`. This IP address seems to work correctly.

When I use `dig` to query my router’s DNS server, it shows the TTL as 1332, but when querying the nameservers directly, I get TTL of 300 – does this mean my router’s DNS server is caching the response for too long, and is its fault?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stack Exchange uses the [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com) CDN.

This means that all the requests you think are going to Stack Exchange are actually going to Cloudflare servers. Cloudflare have multiple servers spread across the world, and multiple servers in each location.

You can see the [list of cloudflare IP ranges on their site](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips). You will notice that both IPs you report in your question are in the same block -- so this is just Cloudflare's load balancing coming into play.

Why one worked for you and another didn't? I'd just blame Gremlins getting into the wires. If it's a continuing issue, possibly switch away from your ISPs DNS servers.